# how can i use Delete function in file IO successfully -- C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, file-io, text-files

I have a text file exist default record (3 record: 1001, 1002, 1003). Now I want to call my delete function and delete assignation record by using record number. However, have some problem existing...
Problem: **I cannot use the entered record number delete assignation record**

Result:

```
Please enter a record number you wanted to delete: 1002

you have entered: 1002

Record in file before delete:
Total record: 3
1001 eric 1 human 10 70.00 home arrived
1002 amy  1 human 20 45.44 home arrived
1003 Tom  3 human 30 10.00 home arrived

DO you want to delete other records? <y/n>: n
```

content in text file after deleted:

```
1001 eric 1 human 10 70.00 home arrived
1001 eric 1 human 10 70.00 home arrived
1001 eric 1 human 10 70.00 home arrived
```

Here is my code (sorry for my long code,  I really want to solve this problem):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    Del_menu();
    return 0;
}

// function1
int Del_menu() {
    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter a record number you wanted to delete : ");
        Del();
        printf("\nDo u want to delete  other record? Enter 'y' for yes and 'n' for no :");
        char ans;
        scanf(" %c", &ans);
        if (ans == 'N' || ans == 'n') {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// function2
int Del() {
    struct record {
        char recordnum[40];
        char itemrecord[40];
        char quantity[40];
        char weight[40];
        char itemname[40];
        char catagory[40];
        char recipient[40];
        char final_destination[40];
        char status[40];
    };

    FILE *fileptr1, *fileptr2;
    char filename[40] = "data.txt";
    int total = 0;  
    int  total_1 = 0 ,total_2 = 0, i = 0 , temp;

    fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    fscanf(fileptr1, "%d", &total);
    int c = total;
    struct record Arr[c];

    total_1 = total; 

    while (total > 0) {  // put data in array
        fscanf(fileptr1, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
                         Arr[i].recordnum,
                         Arr[i].itemname,
                         Arr[i].itemrecord,
                         Arr[i].catagory, 
                         Arr[i].quantity, 
                         Arr[i].weight,
                         Arr[i].recipient,
                         Arr[i].final_destination, 
                         Arr[i].status); 

        i++;
        total--;
    }

    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // clean buffer
    char del_data[41];
    fgets(del_data, 40, stdin);
    del_data[strlen(del_data) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("\nyou have entered :%s\n", del_data);

    total = total_1 ;    //let total change in to default data
    total_2 = total - 1; //total_2 = 2

    printf("\nRecord in file before delete:\n");
    printf("Total record: %d\n",total);
    for(i=0; i<total ;i++) { // output data in the array`
        printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n",
               Arr[i].recordnum, 
               Arr[i].itemname,
               Arr[i].itemrecord,
               Arr[i].catagory, 
               Arr[i].quantity, 
               Arr[i].weight,
               Arr[i].recipient,
               Arr[i].final_destination, 
               Arr[i].status);
    }

    rewind(fileptr1);
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // clean buffer 

    fileptr2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");

    while(total != 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            if (Arr[i].recordnum != del_data) { 
                fprintf(fileptr2, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
                                  Arr[i].recordnum, 
                                  Arr[i].itemname,
                                  Arr[i].itemrecord,
                                  Arr[i].catagory,
                                  Arr[i].quantity, 
                                  Arr[i].weight,
                                  Arr[i].recipient,
                                  Arr[i].final_destination,
                                  Arr[i].status); 
                total--;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }  

    fclose(fileptr1);
    fclose(fileptr2);

    remove(filename);
    // rename the file copy.c to original name
    rename("copy.c", filename);
} // end of function 2
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: The fact that you have deliberately separated user input and user input prompts at *different levels of your program structure* is astounding, and not in a good way. Your architectural decisions, along with your code sloppiness generally, are problematic.

Comment: Additionally, although C no longer requires variables to be declared at the top of your function, youre really abusing that ability.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] - what is your problem exactly?

Comment: There is one simple trick. Download console program called `indent` and use it like: `$ indent -kr myFile.c` - it does pure magic. More about code styles at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one problem is you are not comparing the strings instead you are comparing the pointers.

```
char del_data[41];
char recordnum [40];
if (Arr[i].recordnum != del_data) // Here you are comparing the pointers
```

Change it to:

```
if (strcmp(Arr[i].recordnum, del_data) != 0)
```

> Note:: `strcmp` returns `0` if both the strings are same.
>
> For more info [strcmp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

---

Another problem is you don't need two loops to copy the array contents to new file.

```
while (total != 0) {
    for(i=0; i < total; i++) {
        if (Arr[i].recordnum != del_data) {
            fprintf(fileptr2, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", 
                              Arr[i].recordnum, 
                              Arr[i].itemname,
                              Arr[i].itemrecord,
                              Arr[i].catagory,
                              Arr[i].quantity,
                              Arr[i].weight,
                              Arr[i].recipient,
                              Arr[i].final_destination, 
                              Arr[i].status); 
            total--;
            i++;
        }
    }  
}
```

Where `total--` and `i++` inside `if` is unnecessary.

You can simply rewrite it as:

```
for(i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (strcmp(Arr[i].recordnum, del_data) != 0) {
        fprintf(fileptr2, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
                          Arr[i].recordnum, 
                          Arr[i].itemname,
                          Arr[i].itemrecord,
                          Arr[i].catagory, 
                          Arr[i].quantity, 
                          Arr[i].weight,
                          Arr[i].recipient,
                          Arr[i].final_destination, 
                          Arr[i].status);
    } 
}
```